# Global Error Handling in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, exception

I am using ASP.NET 4.0. Some time user forget to write try-catch block for particular function in a page. It throws exception and the client sees a yellow screen. I don't like that. I have created an Error.aspx page to show error messages. When an error occurs on a page, I am redirecting user to Error.aspx. How to do global error handling in .NET?

Comment: you can define an error handler tag in web.config file which will by default redirect you to this page

Comment: <customErrors mode="On" 
      defaultRedirect="DefaultRedirectErrorPage.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Http404ErrorPage.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to intercept exceptions in ASP.NET. It looks like you are not using MVC. In that case I prefer the Application_Error method in the global.asax file. See here for an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx

You can also use IIS to intercept exceptions and serve a page by using the cusomErrors in the web.config. However, you can not log exceptions this way so it is not preferred as a primary way of error handling. It is however a good practice to set this to a fallback error page as a final catch-all method in the case you have an exception in your primary error page.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly">
   <error redirect="404.aspx" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: Thanks mnwsmit for ur help.I would like to ask u.Suppose there 2 user accessing 2 diff page,both got error,User1 get user1's error and user2, user2's error.User1 will get user2's error
I am confuse because of following line.
Exception excp = Server.GetLastError();

Comment: Interesting thought. I never noticed a problem with this. Either it's a race condition that very rarely happens or Server.GetLastError() always returns the last error for the *current* request.